# Multiple HTTP request happening with single call on frequent network change in android

Tags: java, android, json, httpurlconnection

I am making a HTTP URLconnection for my JSON upload in android. The request is an Intent Service. I have a broadcast receiver which checks for Network change and calls the Intent Service to make the upload. 
But in doing so when a user is frequently changing the network for Wifi to cellular or Vic-verse at times the same JSON is uploaded more than once.

BroadcastReciver.java

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    if (ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION.equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())) {
        if (Utils.hasActiveInternet(context)) {

            TripManager.uploadUnSubmittedTripsAsync(context, DataStore.getApplicationPath(context));

            Logger.log("OSBroadcastReceiver","onReceive",new String[]{"Network available"});

        }else
            Logger.log("OSBroadcastReceiver","onReceive",new String[]{"Network unavailable"});

    } 
}
```

Upload.java

```
private ServiceResponse executeServiceRequestInternal() {
    ServiceResponse serviceResponse = null;
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    boolean delay = false;
    if (!Utils.hasActiveInternet(mContext)) {
        pushError("error");
    } else {

        try {
            if (jsonFile.exists()) {
                do {
                    connection = (HttpURLConnection) getServiceUrl(mRequest.serviceUrl).openConnection();
                    setHttpRequestType(mRequest, connection);
                    setContentType(mRequest, connection);
                    setHeaders(mRequest, connection);

                    connection.setUseCaches(false);
                    connection.setDoInput(true);
                    if (mRequest.requestType != GET_REQUEST) {
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                    }
                    connection.setConnectTimeout(mRequest.requestTimeout);
                    connection.setReadTimeout(mRequest.requestTimeout);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "close");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Keep-Alive", "off");
                    if (mRequest.requestData != null && mRequest.requestData.length() > 0) {
                        sendRequestWithData(connection);
                    }

                    connection.connect();

                    int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

                    if (delay) {
                        Thread.sleep(TIME_BEFORE_RETRY);
                    }
                    if (responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK && responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_ACCEPTED && responseCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
                        String serverResponse = connection.getResponseMessage();
                        if (null == serverResponse) serverResponse = serverError;

                        serviceResponse = getServiceResponse(responseCode,
                                serverResponse);
                        pushServerError(responseCode, serverResponse);
                    } else {
                        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
                        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
                        String line;
                        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
                        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                            response.append(line);
                            response.append('\r');
                        }
                        rd.close();

                        String resultString = response.toString();
                        is.close();
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(resultString)) {
                            serviceResponse = getServiceResponse(
                                    HttpURLConnection.HTTP_NO_CONTENT, "");
                            deleteTrip();
                        } else {
                            serviceResponse = getServiceResponse(
                                    HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK, resultString);
                            deleteTrip();
                        }
                        break;
                    }
                    // we did not succeed with connection (or we would have returned the connection).
                    connection.disconnect();
                    // retry
                    mRetryCounter++;
                    delay = true;

                } while (mRetryCounter < MAX_RETRY_COUNT);


            } else {
                if (connection != null) {
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

    }
    return serviceResponse;
}
```

Thank in advance.

Comment: every time the user changes network he gets disconnected from the previous network and is connected to the new one and your service is called twice. do you check for this ?

Comment: And your question is? If you just want to prevent duplicate uploads just add a counter in your service...

Comment: I am not using a counter but as it's an intent service I am checking for the JSON file is existing or not. but it looks like the internally there is some URLConnection pool holding data which is uploading as per logs

Comment: Try adding  connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

Comment: no luck even then.

Comment: executeServiceRequestInternal() is getting called twice or just request going twice ?

Comment: it is doing a silent request in the background

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and after adding connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(0) it was solved; this is the snippet you can refer,

```
HttpURLConnection request = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            request.setUseCaches(false);
            request.setDoOutput(true);
            request.setDoInput(true);
            request.setConnectTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            request.setRequestMethod(HTTP_POST);
            request.setReadTimeout(CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            request.setChunkedStreamingMode(0);

            DataOutputStream printout = new DataOutputStream(request.getOutputStream());
            NameValuePair dataToSend = new NameValuePair(AppEnvironment.DATA, data);
            // printout.write(getQuery(dataToSend));
            printout.writeBytes(getQuery(dataToSend));
            printout.flush();
            printout.close();




 private String getQuery(NameValuePair params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();


        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(params.getKey(), "UTF-8"));
        result.append("=");
        result.append(URLEncoder.encode(params.getValue(), "UTF-8"));
//        }

        return result.toString();
    }
```

Comment: what request.setChunkedStreamingMode(0); does? Can you please explain its functionality?